# Where can transaction.timeout.ms be set in Flink SQL

Tags: apache-kafka-connect, flink-sql

I use Flink read data from Kafka using FlinkKafkaConsumer, then convert datastream to table, in the end sink data back to kafka(kafka-connector table) with FlinkSQL. In order to get exactly-once delivery guarantees, i set kafka table with property: sink.semantic=exactly-once.
When do test, i got error "transaction timeout is large than the maximum value allowed by the broker".
[image]
Flink default Kafka producer max transaction timeout: 1h
[image]
kafka default setting is transaction.max.timeout.ms=900000.

So, i need to add "transaction.timeout.ms" property in kafka producer. My question is where can i add this property using FlinkSQL.

My code:

```
tableEnv.executeSql("INSERT INTO sink_kafka_table select * from source_table")
```

I have known use with table api

```
tableEnv.connect(new Kafka()
          .version("") 
          .topic("")
          .property("bootstrap.server","")
          .property("transaction.timeout.ms","120000"))
          .withSchema()
          .withFormat()
          .createTemporaryTable("sink_table")
 table.executeInsert("sink_table")
```

It's not good advice to modify kafka config file.
Any advice will help, thanks advance.

Comment: My version information: Flink 1.13.6, and sink_kafka_table create with SQL like
"CREATE TABLE sink_kafka_table(
   col1 STRING,
   col2 STRING
) WITH(
   'connector'='kafka',
   'topic'='sink_kafka_table',
   'properties.bootstrap.servers'='node02:9092',
   'properties.group.id'='sink_kafka_table',
   'scan.startup.mode'='earliest-offset',
   'format'='json'," +
   'json.ignore-parse-errors'='true',
   'json.fail-on-missing-field'='false',
   'json.map-null-key.mode'='LITERAL',
   'json.encode.decimal-as-plain-number'='true',
   'sink.semantic'='exactly-once'
)"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using the connector declaration https://nightlies.apache.org/flink/flink-docs-stable/docs/dev/table/common/#connector-tables you can use the `.option` method to set the [`properties.*`](https://nightlies.apache.org/flink/flink-docs-stable/docs/connectors/table/kafka/#properties) [option](https://nightlies.apache.org/flink/flink-docs-stable/api/java/org/apache/flink/table/api/TableDescriptor.Builder.html#option-java.lang.String-java.lang.String-)  which will be forwarded to the kafka client with `properties.` stripped. So you'll need to set `properties.transaction.max.timeout.ms`

You can also create the `sink_table` with an SQL DDL statement passing any configuration using the `properties.*` option as well: https://nightlies.apache.org/flink/flink-docs-stable/docs/connectors/table/kafka/#properties

I'm not familiar with how are you creating the table, but I think it was deprecated and removed in 1.14: https://nightlies.apache.org/flink/flink-docs-release-1.13/api/java/org/apache/flink/table/api/TableEnvironment.html#connect-org.apache.flink.table.descriptors.ConnectorDescriptor- the method comments recommends creating the table executing a SQL DDL statement.

Comment: I have added information about sink_kafka_table SQL DDL.  With connector-tables can set property using option. I want to use Flink SQL,
https://nightlies.apache.org/flink/flink-docs-stable/docs/connectors/table/kafka/#connector-options, there is no transaction.timeout property.

Comment: It is a Kafka client configuration. You can pass any configuration with the option `properties.<kafka-conf>` https://nightlies.apache.org/flink/flink-docs-stable/docs/connectors/table/kafka/#properties so `properties.transaction.max.timeout.ms` will set the property you want

Comment: Thanks a lot. I missing the `properties.*`. In addition, in FlinkSQL the transaction time property is `properties.transaction.timeout.ms`.